# How to close a local field of JDBCConnectionPool

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a local field of type `JdbcConnectionPool` (h2.jdbcx.JdbcConnectionPool) in my object. Since Java lacks an `IDisposable` Interface as found in .net, how can I ensure having the connection pool closed when the instance of the object is never in use any longer?

```
 import java.sql.*;
 import org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcConnectionPool;
 public class Test {

 private JdbcConnectionPool cp= null;

 private void setupConnectionPool() {
  JdbcConnectionPool cp = JdbcConnectionPool.create(
             "jdbc:h2:~/test", "sa", "sa");
 }

// when to call cp.dispose(); ??

 }
```

Comment: Please, could you complete a bit the information?  Which implementation of ConnectionPool are you usin?

Comment: Sorry. h2.jdbcx.JdbcConnectionPool and Java 1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a ShutdwonHook

```
final Thread mainThread = Thread.currentThread();
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    public void run() {

        //close
        mainThread.join();
    }
});
```

Or if you are using Swing you might be interested in using a WindowListener.

Comment: This hook is only called, wehen the jvm is terminated, correct?

Comment: Yes when the Runtime is going to exit

Comment: Sorry for not beeing more precise with my question. How can I ensure, that the local field (the connection pool instance) is disposed when an instance of that object is "nulled"?
As I said before: just like the IDisposable in .net with the using(...) style.

Comment: finalize() method, but please do not use! The best way is - batch: open connection when the batch start and close when batch stop; - jee: use connection pool of container; - window app: use WindowListener

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will read about the two possibilities you gave me.